# How to force immediate DataDog logging, not after 14 seconds

Tags: datadog

Some time after DataDog is initialized:

```
    datadogLogs.init({
      clientToken: 'TOKEN',
      sampleRate: 100,
      forwardErrorsToLogs: false,
    });
```

I am logging an event:

```
  datadogLogs.logger.log(
    'Something went wrong',
    { env: 'mySpecialEnv' },
    StatusType.warn
  );
```

When there is a problem that will make the user most likely to quit the app altogether.

However, I have noticed it takes 14 seconds since I call the warning to be logged to the time an actual request is sent to DataDog server.

As a result, some events might be not logged at all, because a user will quit before a warning will be sent and saved.

How to force immediate logging with DataDog?

Comment: Which language?

Comment: @mjwills thanks for question. It occured that even query seems to be sent after 14 seconds it is send before. I don't know why. Anyways it works as expected